# How to call a function when a collection contains n elements after an addition of element?

Tags: c#, collections

I am writing some concurrent program that finds improvements on a planning. Multiple threads search for improvements in the planning. When they find one, they add the improvement to a `ConcurrentBag`. When there are *n* improvements in the `ConcurrentBag`, a function should be called that processes all improvements and tells all threads to update their working planning.

Do I have to override the `ConcurrentBag` and change its `.Add` function into something like:

```
Add(Item item)
{
    base.Add(item);
    if (this.Count() > n) SomeStaticClass.ProcessImprovements();
}
```

or is there a better option? Overriding a class for this seems unnecessary to me, but I don't know any better way of doing it.

Is there maby some listener structure or something? Who can help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve this but I would prefer that approach or creating a class that encapsulates the behavior of the ConcurrentBag. Either way you can have full-control and be able to make it behave the way you want it to.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not thread-safe! So more than one thread could call `ProcessImprovements`.